# How does Postgres implement the CUBE-, ROLLUP- and GROUPING SETS operators

Tags: postgresql, set, grouping, cube, rollup

I am interested in how does Postgres implement the CUBE-, ROLLUP- and GROUPING SETS operators?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Postgres doesn't support this yet. The upcoming version 9.5 (currently in beta) will have it: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-select.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The implementation is based on processing sorted data. You can see result of EXPLAIN statement:

```
 postgres=# EXPLAIN SELECT a, b, sum(c) FROM foo GROUP BY ROLLUP(a,b);
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                             QUERY PLAN                             │
╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│ GroupAggregate  (cost=142.54..166.99 rows=405 width=12)            │
│   Group Key: a, b                                                  │
│   Group Key: a                                                     │
│   Group Key: ()                                                    │
│   ->  Sort  (cost=142.54..147.64 rows=2040 width=12)               │
│         Sort Key: a, b                                             │
│         ->  Seq Scan on foo  (cost=0.00..30.40 rows=2040 width=12) │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
(7 rows)

postgres=# EXPLAIN SELECT a, b, sum(c) FROM foo GROUP BY CUBE(a,b);
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                             QUERY PLAN                             │
╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│ GroupAggregate  (cost=142.54..302.48 rows=605 width=12)            │
│   Group Key: a, b                                                  │
│   Group Key: a                                                     │
│   Group Key: ()                                                    │
│   Sort Key: b                                                      │
│     Group Key: b                                                   │
│   ->  Sort  (cost=142.54..147.64 rows=2040 width=12)               │
│         Sort Key: a, b                                             │
│         ->  Seq Scan on foo  (cost=0.00..30.40 rows=2040 width=12) │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
(9 rows)
```

Data are sorted, and then continually aggregated.

Comment: error :function rollup (text) does not exist for postgres version 9.3.16 !

Comment: @RizwanPatel - sure - it is supported by PostgreSQL 9.5 and higher